# javax.persistence.persistenceexception exception eclipselink-4002 (eclipse persistence services - 2.5.2.v 20140319

Tags: java

I have this error and I tried many things but I don't know where the problem is.

I am working with the architecture Jpa/Eclipselink/OpenEJB and I want to test a Class Test JUnit in order to put some recordings in Database.

The error is

> Results :
>
> Tests in error: 
>    initDB(dao.JUnitInitDBLocal): javax.persistence.PersistenceException: >Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
>
> ---
>
> ### BUILD FAILURE
>
> Total time: 1:05.219s
>   Finished at: Fri Jul 24 22:47:36 CEST 2015
>
> ### Final Memory: 6M/15M
>
> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-cli) on project mv-pam-openejb-eclipselink: There are test failures.
>
> Please refer to C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Chapitre 5\mv-pam-openejb-eclipselink\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
>   -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

This is my Class Test :

```
package dao;

import jpa.Cotisation;
import jpa.Employe;
import jpa.Indemnite;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class JUnitInitDB {

 static private IEmployeDao employeDao = null;
 static private ICotisationDao cotisationDao = null;
 static private IIndemniteDao indemniteDao = null;

@BeforeClass
public static void init()  {
    // configuration de l'application
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config-dao.xml");
    // couches dao
    employeDao = (IEmployeDao) ctx.getBean("employeDao");
    cotisationDao = (ICotisationDao) ctx.getBean("cotisationDao");
    indemniteDao = (IIndemniteDao) ctx.getBean("indemniteDao");
}

@Test
public void initDB() {


    Indemnite indemnite1 = indemniteDao.create(new Indemnite(1, 1.93, 2, 3, 12));
    Indemnite indemnite2 = indemniteDao.create(new Indemnite(2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 15));
    Employe employe2 = employeDao.create(new Employe("254104940426058", "LACHRAF", "Younes", "5 rue des oiseaux", "St Corentin", "49203", indemnite2));
    Employe employe1 = employeDao.create(new Employe("260124402111742", "Laverti", "Justine", "La br�lerie", "St Marcel", "49014", indemnite1));
    Cotisation cotisation1 = cotisationDao.create(new Cotisation(3.49, 6.15, 9.39, 7.88));
    System.out.println("Employés ----------------------");
    for (Employe employe : employeDao.findAll()) {
        System.out.println(employe);
    }
    System.out.println("Indemnités ----------------------");
    for (Indemnite indemnite : indemniteDao.findAll()) {
        System.out.println(indemnite);
    }
    System.out.println("Cotisations ----------------------");
    for (Cotisation cotisation : cotisationDao.findAll()) {
        System.out.println(cotisation);
    }
}

@Before()
public void clean() {
    for (Employe employe : employeDao.findAll()) {
        employeDao.destroy(employe);
    }
    for (Cotisation cotisation : cotisationDao.findAll()) {
        cotisationDao.destroy(cotisation);
    }
    for (Indemnite indemnite : indemniteDao.findAll()) {
        indemniteDao.destroy(indemnite);
    }

}


 @AfterClass
 public static void terminate() throws Exception {
 }
}
```

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="dbpam_eclipselinkPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- le fournisseur JPA est EclipseLink -->
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- entités Jpa -->
    <class>jpa.Cotisation</class>
    <class>jpa.Employe</class>
    <class>jpa.Indemnite</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my Pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mv-pam-openejb-eclipselink</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>                
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
        <id>eclipselink</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I Think the problem is in this three Files cause I tested the others Packages Jpa, Dao, Exception in other architecture and the test passed.

if any one can help me i will be grateful .

---

My Eception Class is :

```
package exception;

import javax.ejb.ApplicationException;

@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class PamException extends RuntimeException {
// code d'erreur
private int code;
public PamException(int code) {
super();
this.code = code;
}
public PamException(String message, int code) {
super(message);
this.code = code;
}
public PamException(Throwable cause, int code) {
super(cause);
this.code = code;
}
public PamException(String message, Throwable cause, int code) {
super(message, cause);
this.code = code;
}
// getter et setter
public int getCode() {
return code;
}
public void setCode(int code) {
this.code = code;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there some more information from the exception? Looks like a communication/login problem with the database. Searching for `EclipseLink-4002`shows some exception followed by detailed information.

Comment: This is my Exception Class :